# Comparison of multilevel models via deviance test

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, likelihood-ratio

I have a question regarding the comparison of the following two multilevel models:

1. Null model: outcome.nullmodel <- lmer(outcome ~ 1 + (1 | ID), data=multileveldata)
2. Random slopes model: outcome.rs <- lmer(outcome ~ 1+ predictor_L1+(1+predictor_L1|ID), data = multileveldata)

I read in some articles that a random slopes model of that kind was compared to a null model/intercept only via deviance/likelihood-ratio test. But is it appropriate to use the deviance test here? I am not sure about that because the models differ in the fixed AND the random effect. Therefore, I would assume they are non-nested and should be compared using information criteria such as AIC and/or BIC instead of likelihood ration test. Or am I wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for your support!

Answer (score 2):

The models are still nested: you get model 1 by setting the coefficient of `predictor_L1` and the variance component for `predictor_L1` and the covariance component to zero.  That's just three parameters.

It's a slightly non-standard likelihood ratio test, because the null value of the variance component is on the boundary of the parameter space, but there isn't an issue with nesting.